# How to know when a web worker fails to load?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, web-worker

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to know whether loading a web worker failed (e.g., because I'm trying to load it from a URL and I'm getting a 404 back).

The problem I have is that when starting the worker fails, I just get an unspecific event passed to the onerror listener. This is also the callback that gets executed when there is an error after the worker starts (e.g., any exception inside the worker will also be caught by onerror). So my problem is that I need to be able to find out if the worker has simply failed to load to do some specific error handling for this case, or if the call to onerror has happened because there was an exception in the worker code.

So far the only difference I've been able to tell is that when the worker fails to load, the event doesn't have any "message", "filename", "lineno" and "colno" properties, which are present in exceptions. But exploiting this feels rather hacky and a source of cross-browser issues, so I wonder if there is a cleaner way to figure out what went wrong.

By the way, right now the code I'd use to handle my errors would look something like this:

```
const worker = new Worker("my_worker.js");

worker.onerror = (e) => {
    if (!e.filename) {
        // worker failed to load
    } else {
        // exception inside the worker
    }
};
```

Thanks!